# How to remove the let variable on this code

Tags: javascript

I have the following function, I would like to remove/rewrite the `let comparison` variable but still using the `.reduce`.
Any idea for an elegant solution using latest js?

```js
const isTargetPresent = (input, target) => {
  let comparison = "";
  return [...input].reduce((acc, value) => {
    comparison += value;
    return acc || comparison.indexOf(target) >= 0;
  }, false);
};

console.log(isTargetPresent('hello home', 'hello'));
console.log(isTargetPresent('hello banana', 'apple'));
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using indexOf or RegEx?

Comment: In general, I'd handle it with `const isTargetPresent = (input, target) => input.indexOf(target) >= 0;`. `reduce` is pointless here.

Comment: Why are you using the spread operator?

Comment: Is it possible to emove the `let` without touching the rest?

Comment: Of course not @Radex. This is where the string is built.

Answer (score 3):

You are overcomplicating things imo. Here is a way simpler implementation:

```js
const isTargetPresent = (input, target) => {

  return input.indexOf(target) >= 0;

};

console.log(isTargetPresent('hello home', 'hello'));
console.log(isTargetPresent('hello banana', 'apple'));
```

Comment: So are you! The ternary operator is pointless `const isTargetPresent = (input, target) => !!~input.indexOf(target);`

Comment: then why not `const isTargetPresent = (input, target) => input.includes(target)`   :p

Comment: That is even shorter yes, nice thinking!